# Show nested values in chart with groups using c3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, c3.js

I have a block of JSON data looking like this:

```
{
            date: '2014-01-01',
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Janos",
                    work: 3,
                    drive: 5
                },
                {
                    name: "Jelle",
                    work: 4,
                    drive: 2
                }
            ]
        }, {
            date: '2014-01-02',
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Janos",
                    work: 3,
                    drive: 5
                },
                {
                    name: "Jelle",
                    work: 4,
                    drive: 2
                }
            ]

        }, {
            date: '2014-01-03',
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Janos",
                    work: 3,
                    drive: 5
                },
                {
                    name: "Jelle",
                    work: 4,
                    drive: 2
                }
            ]

        }, {
            date: '2014-01-04',
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Janos",
                    work: 3,
                    drive: 5
                },
                {
                    name: "Jelle",
                    work: 4,
                    drive: 2
                }
            ]

        }
```

And I want a line chart with an x axis based on the date key, and columns based on the given names in the data arrays for each item.

So for each person I want to show the work **and** drive value.

This is what I'm trying to achieve (in case I don't make any sense):

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]
*Achieved this screenshot by using inspect element*

I hope my question makes sense, I can't seem to make it work with the available documentation.

Please leave a comment if I'm not clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might want to look at that [simple d3 graph](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5)
If you already have a code and want help with it, paste it here or make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Comment: @JackRed I've tried altering the https://c3js.org/samples/data_json.html example however I can't find any example on "grouping" the data like shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I think [this example](https://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy_multiple.html) is better 
You just have to adapt your data a bit. I'll try to do something

Comment: Do you mind waiting a bit? I'm getting around c3.js. I founded everything I need and putting it together to give you an answer

Comment: No problem! Eager to see your answer.

Comment: Ok, I have a bad news. I tought that c3 was able to handle object (or array) (or anything other than date and number) but it's not the case
I tried to trick it using float numbers and then parsing with the '.' but it doesn't really work
The solution is a d3 solution and not c3 (or I don't know c3 enough, but the documentation is not at all user friendly so it's not easy)
However, I can help you with d3 if you need

Comment: The example screenshot doesn't make sense as each person is shown as a different colour in the tooltip, but each attribute (drive/work) is then assigned those same two colours in the legend. If for each person you want to show the drive AND work, then you're wanting a line graph with 4 lines on it?